# Birt Engine Report need to add download link in each row

Tags: report, birt

I am using Birt engine to generate report in our java web application. I need to add a download link for each row which generated. can you help me how can i add this option in my report.

Answer (score 0):

That is quite easy to do. You can select any label or data field on your report or table.

1. Open the properties editor and open the tab 'Hyperlink'
2. click edit
3. select URI
4. open the expression editor by selecting javascript syntax right next to the *location* field.
5. Now you can build a dynamic link based the columns in your dataset/table.
6. for example: "http://" + row["myUrl"] + "/"
7. OK your way back and enjoy the result.